# How to detect 404 response code from IO exception?

Tags: java, android

How are you suppose to detect a 404 from an IO exception. I could just search the error message for "404", but is that the correct way?   Anything more direct?

```
  import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
  import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Update;
  import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;


    File result = null;

    try {

        update = drive.files().update(driveId, file , mediaContent);
        update.setNewRevision(true);

        result = update.execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "file update exception, statusCode: " + update.getLastStatusCode());
        Log.e(TAG, "file update exception, e: " + e.getMessage());

    }   

Log.e(TAG, "file update exception, statuscode " + update.getLastStatusCode());

03-03 05:04:31.738: E/System.out(31733): file update exception, statusCode: -1
03-03 05:04:31.738: E/System.out(31733): file update exception, e: 404 Not Found
03-03 05:04:31.738: E/System.out(31733): "message": "File not found: FileIdRemoved",
```

Answer:  Aegan's comment below was correct, turns out you can subclass the the exception to a GoogleJsonResponseException and from there get the status code.   The answer in this case ultimately depended on the fact I am using a GoogleClient, which generates a subclass of IO Exception that contains the status code.

Example:

```
Try{
    ...
    }catch (IOException e) {

      if(e instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException){
          int statusCode = ((GoogleJsonResponseException) e).getStatusCode();
          //do something
   }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you are getting a subClass of IOException for 404?

Comment: Correct! I get a GoogleJsonResponseExpection, which when casted to, contains a getStatusCode() method.  If you would like to write it up, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle `HttpResponseException`:

```
catch (HttpResponseException hre) {
   if (hre.getStatusCode() == 404) {
      // TODO: Handle Http 404 
   }
}
```

**Detail:** 
`AbstractGoogleClientRequest` creates exceptions.[See source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java/?v=source)

[`execute`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java#AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute%28%29) method calls [`executeUnparsed`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java#AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed%28%29). `executeUnparsed` creates exception with [`newExceptionOnError`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java#AbstractGoogleClientRequest.newExceptionOnError%28com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse%29). There you will see, it throws a `HttpResponseException`(which is a subclass of `IOException`)

Comment: Dead on, catches the superclass that GoogleJsonResponseException extends from, for a more generalized answer than I wrote up after your comment.

Comment: If you put it as the first catch clause (before IOException) that'll work.

Comment: yah, i reordered my exceptions to avoid having to cast :)

Comment: `HttpResponseException` is the parent-class of `GoogleJsonResponseException`, correct? How is it then possible that GoogleJsonResponseException is not being caught by a catch( HttpResponseException ) in my app ?

Answer (score 2):

You should to get response error code.

I made little example:

```
int code = con.getResponseCode(); 
if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
    // Handle error
}
else {
    // Do your work
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found the right mechanism to find this in the Google Drive SDK.  You can see my update, I try update.getLastStatusCode(), but its returning -1, while the error message contains a 404.

Comment: @NameSpace `I haven't found the right mechanism to find this in the Google SDK` - ??? getResponseCode() has been there since API 1.

Comment: I know you're getting getReponseCode() from an HttpURLConnection, but I never used or created that class to upload the files with the drive client.  How would i get access to that class from the client or update task?